# How to update value in Spring Validator

Tags: java, spring, spring-validator

In our application, we are creating custom validators by implementing ConstraintValidator. It runs for one annotation which is Field Level. 
User can enter data irrespective of case but in database we have entire data in uppercase. We want a way to update fields which are annotated by this annotation to be converted to uppercase in this Validator and same value should be reflected in following program execution. Spring Convertor we are avoiding as field is String so it will add a lot of overhead but if there is optimised way, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I don't think altering the data conceptually matches the goal of JSR-303... You could weave an aspect to do that job (either using a Spring Converter or an ad-hoc interface), and a bit of config will make this happen before the validation. But hacking around ConstraintValidator to do so looks quite bad to me...

Comment: Thanks for reply and I completely agree with you, @spi. But we are in that situation where we need to trade off between specification and performance. If we create Converter on String fields then for every action it will be called and hence it will have huge impact on performance. Any thought regarding handling this situation is welcome.

Comment: how do you know the impact is huge? did you measure it, and did it prove to be the bottleneck? and a spring converter is not the only option. You could use a http filter, or an aspect weaved only to the method of your choice. And maybe other options